# Objective-c object call

Tags: objective-c, cordova

Can anyone tell me what this line of code does?

```
self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
```

viewController is already a CDVViewController object, so I am not quite sure what its doing with MainViewController :S?

Any help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line simply creates a new object, instance of the class MainViewController, and stores its pointer in the variable viewController.

Comment: But I dont understand as viewController already points to CDVViewController :S

Comment: Also if thats the case, how would I accesses some of the variables and methods in MainViewController from viewController? Would it be something like self.viewController[MainViewController.test = self.test]; ??

Comment: If viewController already contains a pointer to an object, the old pointer will be replaced by the new one.

Comment: And no, your example is not good at all. To call the method test on viewController, you could do something like [[self viewController] test], or self.viewController.test, or [self.viewController test]

Comment: I do that but then it tells me that 'test' does not exist in viewController as its a CDVViewController object. If I place a break point below the line and then run the print object command it displays: (CDVViewController *) $0 = 0x00177500 <MainViewController: 0x177500>

Comment: In the .h file viewController is defined as:

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet CDVViewController* viewController;

Comment: yah it does not seem to make much senses but this is the base structure of a Phonegap application using 2.01. MainViewController also inherits CDViewController so I do not under stand why its not defined as MainViewController in the first place

Comment: If I do the following:

self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
self.viewController.token = "@hello";

The project fails and I get the following error:
Property 'token' not found on object type 'CDVViewController :S'

Answer (score 0):

First it create and init a MainViewController* object, then it assign it to [self setViewController: ].  self.viewController is actually a call on the self setter method, not a simple pointer assignment (not like viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init], if viewController is not an ivar).

Depending on how you generated setter with the @property statement, but let's say it was a

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)*UIViewController viewController
```

You get for free a generated setter method created like this form:

```
- (void)setViewController:(UIViewController*)controller{
    if(viewController != controller){
      [viewController autorelease];
     viewController = [controller retain];
    }
}
```

So if your viewController was a CDVViewController* object, it is now swapping with a new CDVViewController* object. CDVViewController* is now released and CDVViewController is retained and assigned to viewController ivar.

By the way if you just done assignment, you'll should do:

```
[viewController release]; // if it was before a CDVViewController
self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
```

With retained property

```
self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; // it will be retained in the setter, so you must free it
```

Depending on your code, for avoiding leaks.

Comment: The viewController is declared as:

@property(nonatomic, retain)*CDVViewController viewController

After this line of code is done:

self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

How would I set a MainViewController property?

trying to do self.viewController.token = @"hello"; 

Results in an error stating that token is not a property of CDVViewController :S

Comment: ((MainViewController*)(self.viewController)).token = @"hello". So that compiler will not cry. But first do control if your viewController is actually a MainViewController*, cause that will make your program cry too if that not the case. *** -_- By the way you should not declare a CDVViewController* if this not always the case. -_- ***

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. What I dont understand is the way this is all done, from a quick google my understanding is, CDVViewController is declared, and then we can also initiate the MainViewController in order to make use of polymorphism so MainViewController can override certain methods that would otherwise be done through CDVViewController. However MainViewController already inherits CDVViewController, so could viewController not be declared as MainViewController instead of CDVViewContoller, would that not work in the same way?

Comment: What i've done is transtyping, not polymorphism. But yeah, if MainViewController* is subclass of CDVViewController*, you can call CDVViewController* methods on both, since they both include CDVViewController* method. (same way for UIViewController method, or NSObjet method, etc...). But you cannot call MainViewController* specific method since CDVViewController doesn't implement them. There's tone of books on design pattern, you should give a try